# Can not start bundle in Karaf, having grace period status

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

can not resolve bundle in karaf.
Here logs:

```
2016-04-08 05:01:02,323 | INFO  | h for user karaf | BlueprintContainerImpl           
| 17 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.4 |
Bundle io.subutai.core.kurjun.impl/4.0.0.RC7-SNAPSHOT is waiting for dependencies 
[(&(&(!(org.apache.aries.jpa.proxy.factory=*))(osgi.unit.name=PU-KURJUN))(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory))]
```

In this module creating db, using openjpa for that.

Comment: This is not a failure to resolve. Your bundle is started, but your blueprint container times out while waiting for an `EntityManagerFactory` service to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your bundle needs an EntityManagerFactory service for your persistence unit. This can be a bit difficult to track down.

You have to check that you have a bundle that defines this persistence unit, that it is correctly announced using the Manifest header and also that you have a suitable DataSource defined.

For the new error you get I think the problem is that you inject an EnityManagerFactory while I think you need to inject an EntityManager.

Comment: checked, I think missing package, how I can add to Manifest header. I'm trying add in <Import-package> here </Import-package> in apache felix plugin no results.

Comment: Take look at my example for a model bundle: https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi/model .. also look at the parent pom one level up.

Comment: @EricPro It's not a missing import package; your bundle is resolving and starting fine.

Comment: The first thing you need to check is that when installing the bundle containing the persistence unit you actually get a EntityManagerFactory service created for it. You can check that on the karaf console using service:list EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Seems resolved issue with waiting dependecy @ChristianSchneider checked I have persistence unit it that list. now having another problem. Will edit above.